# Are there anyways to find out what caused the crash? Ionic app build is successful but the app crashes on start

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

During build i get the following error.

:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

And the app crashes just when it starts.
Are there any ways to solve the issue.
I am quite new to ionce. So all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you could started the app, it means that :compileDebugJavaWithJavac was just a warning.. If you app is crashing, you must check the LOGCAT.

Comment: Where is the logCAt?